# Can halal food be haram?

Tags: halal-haram, non-muslim, food, parents, family

My family are not muslims and they eat haram food. However I often see them touching halal food after touching a haram food without cleaning their hands.

My question is: **Does the halal food become haram if they touch it after touching a haram food?**

Please someone help me and please provide evidence from reputable sheikh if that is possible. Thank you very much.

Comment: Simply touching something doesn't make it haram if it was halal nor halal if it was haram. This doesn't need any evidence since it is simple logic. However halal food can turn into haram for example many kinds of fruits etc. by fermentation, so once you get the taste of alcohol in such a food it is haram. In Islam specific items or kinds of food are declared haram by the qur'an anything else is by default halal unless any textual evidence exists that may say otherwise.

Comment: Thank you so much I was really worried and you helped me a lot